# Qt paint on a widget created by QT Designer

Tags: qt, user-interface, qt-designer, qpainter, paintevent

How can I paint on a widget without overwriting the `paintEvent`.

I want to paint on a widget which is inside another one generated by Qt Designer , so i can't overwrite its `paintEvent`.

I tried to paint directly like this :

```
QPainter *painter= new QPainter(ui->drawArea);
painter.drawLine(50,50,50,150);
painter.close();
```

but Qt tell me that the `QPainDevice` is 0 or something like this,

I tried the same example by creating the painter then call the `begin()` method with the `QPaintDevice` (the widget) but same problem.

Qt version : 4.8.6.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Qt Painter outside paintEvent - impossible - workaround?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742540/qt-painter-outside-paintevent-impossible-workaround)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using custom widgets in Designer is not an issue. In Designer, add your widget as any other QWidget or QPushButton, depending which has the closest inheritance. Then with right click menu select `Promote to ...`, add your `MyWidget.h` and then promote the widget to `MyWidget` with reimplemented `paintEvent()`. Read more:

http://doc-snapshots.qt.io/4.8/designer-using-custom-widgets.html#promoting-widgets